# Rails: How to wrap the generated "select" with a "div" tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I use a custom `select_with_new_option` method in my form like this:

```
<%= select_with_new_option(f, :shop, :name, :id) %>
```

Here is it's definition:

```
def select_options_with_create_new(objects, text_field, value_field, options={})
  object = objects.to_s.singularize
  all_objects = object.capitalize.constantize.all
  all_objects = all_objects.sort_by(&options[:order_by]) if options.has_key?(:order_by)
  select_options = all_objects.map{ |obj| [obj.send(text_field), obj.send(value_field)] }
  select_options << [wrap_create_new_option("create new #{object}".titleize), "new_#{object}"]
end

def wrap_create_new_option(str)
  ">> #{str} <<"
end

# By default, sorts by 'text_field'.
def select_with_new_option(f, object, text_field, value_field)
  f.select(:"#{object}_id", select_options_with_create_new(object.pluralize, text_field, value_field, :order_by => text_field), 
           {:prompt => true},    # options
           {})                   # html_options
end
```

This creates the `select` tag and it's `option`s as expected.

Now, I want to wrap this `select` with a `div` like this:

```
<div class='my_class'>
  <select>...</select>
</div>
```

What would be the easiest way to do this in "Rails way" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [content_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) method:

```
def select_with_new_option(f, object, text_field, value_field)
  html = f.select(:"#{object}_id",
           select_options_with_create_new(object.pluralize, text_field, value_field, :order_by => text_field), 
           {:prompt => true},    # options
           {})                   # html_options
  content_tag :div, html, :class => "my_class"
end
```

Comment: Where do you put this code?

Comment: @drjorgepolanco in a helper

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to modify your method, you can pass it to the content_tag method as a block:

```
<%= content_tag :div, :class => "my_class" do %>
    <%= select_with_new_option(:f, :shop, :name, :id) %>
<% end %>
```